# Parameter is not valid Exception in creating new Bitmap in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exception, bitmap

We have a method to save an image as corrected format as the following :

```
public static string SaveImageAsCorrectFormat(string tempFilePath, string newFileName, string destinationDirectoryPath)
{
    using (Image image = new Bitmap(tempFilePath))// Exception : Parameter is not valid.
    {
        string extension = image.RawFormat.GetExtension();
        string newAbsoluteFilePath = Path.Combine(destinationDirectoryPath, string.Format("{0}.{1}", newFileName, extension));
        image.Save(newAbsoluteFilePath, image.RawFormat);
        return newAbsoluteFilePath;
    }
}
```

but in in the following line an exception has occurred :

```
//Parameter is not valid.
using (Image image = new Bitmap(tempFilePath))
```

I changed it to the following but `Out of memory` has occurred :

```
 // Out of memory
using (Bitmap image = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(tempFilePath))
```

The image size is 10KB and 10GB of RAM is free.

What's the problem?

**P.S:**
I don't have the problem in local. But when I publish the software on server this problem occur.

**Edit:**
I'm using `windows Server 2012 R2` and `IIS 8.5.9600.16384`. The Application (website) has full control on `IIS_IUSRS` and `IUSR`.
I think the problem isn't related to permission, because I could open the file with the following code :

```
using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open(tempFilePath, FileMode.Open)) // OK
using (Image image = new Bitmap(fileStream))// Exception : Parameter is not valid.
```

**Solution:**
I changed website `application pool identity` to `Local System` and it's OK now, Is it OK to change application pool identity or it is a security hole ?

Comment: well, presumably either the folder in 'tempFilePath'  doesn't exist or you don't have permission to access it if it does exist

Comment: Regarding "Out of memory", check the [MSDN documentation of Image.FromFile(), section "Exceptions"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5.aspx)

Comment: @MitchWheat: There are some directories in `tempFilePath`, created by software. How can I check the permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to grant permission to the folder you are trying to access through your web application. If you are using cPanel [check here](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/cpanel/file_permissions.htm).

Comment: please try it again after adding "Everyone" to the folder's permission and see if it works. Also are you using a 'relative address' or an 'absolute address'.

Comment: I added `Everyone` with FullControl, but the exception occurred again. I'm using 'absolute address'

Comment: Try using 'relative addressing' and please add more detail about the error can you find a error code/no.

Comment: I change website application pool identity to `Local System` and it's OK now, Is it OK to change `application pool identity` or it is an security hole ?

Comment: as far as i know if you have granted the permissions correctly and the database and the website are on the same server there is no problem. you can get more information about the security issues [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/264592/changing-iis-application-pool-identity-to-local-system).

Comment: @Mohammad Also, if this answer has helped you to solve your problem, then please accept it as is customary on this website.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the image is corrupted, or maybe just has the wrong file extension.

If the extension is `jpeg`, .NET will attempt to decode it as a JPEG. Note that this behaviour differs from browsers: browsers tend to look at the content of the file and decide its format based on that; due to this, you could be under the misconception that a `jpeg` file is fine because it displays in the browser, when in reality it contains a PNG image.

If you open the image file in Firefox, the window titlebar tells you what the *real* file format is independent of its file extension.

Comment: I copied the image file from server to my system, and I could open it with `new Bitmap(filePath)`? Is the file corrupted ?

Answer (score 0):

Late in the day but I could not find a reliable workaround. Sometimes environmental issues will affect operation.  In my case I retried the action a number of times if an exception occurred. If you take this approach your action should succeed but make sure the action is idempotent.

e.g. in C#

```
Action action = () => { //call SaveImageAsCorrectFormat }
try {
  action();
}
catch
{
  try {
    action();
  catch (Exception exception) {
    //handle
  }
}
```